# Python 3- password check

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

Here is the problem: write a function that checks whether a string is valid password.

Rules: Must have at least 8 characters A password must consist of only letters and digits A password must contain at least 2 digits

I am having trouble with def CountsDigitsFor, I want it to check for at least 2 digits.

```
def getPassword():
   return input("Enter password: ")

def CountDigitsFor(password):
   res = []
   for i in password:
        if i.isdigit():
           res.append(i)
   return int

def validPassword(password):
   if len(password) >= 8:
      if password.isalnum():
         if CountDigitsFor(password) >= 2:
            return True
   else:
      return False

def main():
   password = getPassword()
   if validPassword(password):
      print(password + " is valid")
   else:
      print(password + " is invalid")

main()
```

Comment: `return int` makes no sense. Replace it with `return len(res)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return int
```

is just returning the class `int`.  What you want to return is the number of digits.  That of course would be:

```
return len(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use this one:

```
def CountDigitsFor(password):
   return sum(character.isdigit() for character in password)
```

I have provided the above in your other question, but just in case that wasn't clear I am going to give you a brief description on how this works.

The above is equivalent to what you want but in one single line. The idea is that you loop through the characters of the password, check if the character is a number and then get the sum of the digits in the password.

Then after you call the `CountDigitsFor()` you will get the **number of digits** in the password and you can check if they are at least 2 with the if statement you have provided.

```
if CountDigitsFor(password) >= 2:
            return True
```

Comment: My professor is anal about using stuff she hasn't gone over yet!